# How to iterate over a variable in rep()

Tags: r, dplyr, rep

this question has been asked a couple of times but I have yet to find a satisfactory answer that works.

I have a dataframe:

```
grouping1 <- rep(c('a','b'),times=47350)
grouping2 <- rep(c('A','B', 'C', 'D', 'E'), times=18940)
observations <- rep(c(14, 16, 12, 11, 15, 15,15,18,20,34,12), times=9470)
my_data <- as.data.frame(cbind(grouping1,grouping2,observations))
```

I would like to group over my grouping variables to pass a different value to `'times'` in `rep()` for each group:

```
new_data <- my_data %>%
group_by(grouping1,grouping2,grouping3) %>%
mutate(sim_count = rep(1:100, times=observations, each=1))
```

But the 'times' argument is invalid, no matter if I pipe in a list of values from 'observations' iterate over 'observations' from the dataframe, iterate through observations in a for loop, etc. I think there must be an easy fix but I'm not seeing it. Thank you in advance.

EDIT: Thanks to everyone for their patience; they helped me better envision the data structure and how I could better explain the problem. Here's the solution I came up with:

```
new_data <- my_data %>%
distinct(grouping1,grouping2,.keep_all=T) %>%
rowwise() %>%
mutate(sim_count = list(rep(1:100,times=observations,each=1))) %>%
unnest_longer(sim_count) %>%
arrange(sim_count)
```

Comment: Are you possibly trying to create 100 instances of the dataframe and `rbind` them? Could you provide an example of output you are expecting to see?

Comment: Also, your data is a `"matrix"`, not a frame, so your code appears to be incorrect (`dplyr` does not work on matrices). Perhaps you mean `my_data <- data.frame(...)` or `tibble(...)`?

Comment: Yes, my_data is a dataframe (edited to clarify that in the code instead of just the prose)

Comment: MeC, it seems that your sample data is not sufficiently representative. One way forward is to update your sample data in a few ways: (a) 2-3 distinct groups, I think it's clear you have "multiple" grouping variables, I think that can be generalized to just one or two actual grouping variables here; (b) 2-3 rows per group; (c) `observations` on a much-smaller scale, perhaps between 2 and 4; (d) *not* `1:100`, perhaps just `1:3` or so. With that, manually build what you expect the output to be, and then we can *very easily* help you do it programmatically/efficiently. Thanks!

Comment: One of the key points of that last comment is that it is something much smaller than your current 94K rows. We don't need that many rows to get the point across. Out of those last four sub-points ("a" through "d"), at least provide a counting example with a group that has more than 1 row, and how many rows you expect in the end.

Comment: Yes, thank you. I've gotten myself entirely turned around and made this way more complicated than it needs to be. For each group, I want to fill a column with the sequence 1:100 repeated N times where N=observations. So a grouped variable with 1400 rows will have 1:100 repeated 14 times. The dataframe does not grow longitudinally. I hope that clarifies my intention.

Comment: I think I figured it out, so I've added my solution above.

Answer (score 1):

We can make a list-column and then `tidyr::unnest` it:

```r
my_data %>%
  group_by(grouping1, grouping2, grouping3) %>%
  mutate(sim_count = lapply(observations, function(obs) rep(1:100, times = obs, each = 1))) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  tidyr::unnest(sim_count)
# # A tibble: 8,300 x 5
#    grouping1 grouping2 grouping3 observations sim_count
#    <chr>     <chr>     <chr>            <dbl>     <int>
#  1 a         A         1                   14         1
#  2 a         A         1                   14         2
#  3 a         A         1                   14         3
#  4 a         A         1                   14         4
#  5 a         A         1                   14         5
#  6 a         A         1                   14         6
#  7 a         A         1                   14         7
#  8 a         A         1                   14         8
#  9 a         A         1                   14         9
# 10 a         A         1                   14        10
# # ... with 8,290 more rows
```

Data

```r
my_data <- structure(list(grouping1 = c("a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b"), grouping2 = c("A", "A", "B", "B", "C", "C"), grouping3 = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"), observations = c(14, 16, 12, 11, 15, 15)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

Comment: I apologize that I did not explain myself clearer, because I was just presenting a toy dataset. Each group in the actual dataframe contains X unique observations, that were simulated 100 times. For ex. 14 observations*100=rep(1:100,times=14). I just want to number each of my unique simulations (n=100).

Comment: Yeah, this has been confused into a bad place. If (say) `id="A"` (some combination of groupings) has 3 rows initially and an `observations` value of 7, then how many rows are you expecting in the resulting frame?

Comment: And also ... with individual `observations` values, why not just do this `rowwise()`? There seems to be some data-architecture issues that I'm not understanding.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe we can try the following `data.table` option

```
setDT(my_data)[
  ,
  .(observations,
    sim_count = rep(1:100, times = observations, each = 1)
  ), grouping1:grouping3
]
```

Comment: This still throws an "invalid times argument" error